# npm install error with kurento - docker

Tags: node.js, linux, docker, npm-install, kurento

I am trying to install kurento media server and one tutorial on the same in Docker container.

Kurento Media server Installation guide:

http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation_guide.html

Kurento Tutorial installation: (using node.js):

http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/node/tutorial-one2one.html

First I have tried installing the same in ubuntu machine , Manually executed each command so that I can see it is working fine.

But when I am trying to install the same inside docker container it is not working fine.

Dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
MAINTAINER USER1 "USER1@infinte.com"
RUN echo 'debconf debconf/frontend select Noninteractive' | debconf-set-selections
RUN apt-get update
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y -q python-software-properties software-properties-common
RUN apt-get install wget -y
RUN apt-get install git -y
RUN apt-get install curl -y
RUN echo "deb http://ubuntu.kurento.org trusty kms6" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kurento.list
RUN wget -O - http://ubuntu.kurento.org/kurento.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install kurento-media-server-6.0 -y
RUN sudo service kurento-media-server-6.0 start
RUN sudo service kurento-media-server-6.0 stop
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo bash -
RUN sudo apt-get install -y nodejs -y
RUN sudo npm install -g bower -y
RUN git clone https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-node.git
RUN cd kurento-tutorial-node/kurento-one2one-call && pwd
RUN cd kurento-tutorial-node/kurento-one2one-call && git checkout 6.1.0
RUN sudo service kurento-media-server-6.0 start
RUN sudo apt-get install build-essential -y
RUN apt-get install python2.7-dev -y
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN cd kurento-tutorial-node/kurento-one2one-call && sudo npm install
EXPOSE 8443
```

I am getting the error which is as follows:

Error is occurring during the npm install command.

```
Step 25 : RUN cd kurento-tutorial-node/kurento-one2one-call && npm install
 ---> Running in d8c66e73f94f

> utf-8-validate@1.1.0 install /kurento-tutorial-node/kurento-one2one-call/node_modules/ws/node_modules/utf-8-validate
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory `/kurento-tutorial-node/kurento-one2one-call/node_modules/ws/node_modules/utf-8-validate/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/validation.node
  COPY Release/validation.node
make: Leaving directory `/kurento-tutorial-node/kurento-one2one-call/node_modules/ws/node_modules/utf-8-validate/build'
npm WARN cannot run in wd ws@0.4.32 (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0) (wd=/kurento-tutorial-node/kurento-one2one-call/node_modules/kurento-client/node_modules/reconnect-ws/node_modules/websocket-stream/node_modules/ws)

> bufferutil@1.1.0 install /kurento-tutorial-node/kurento-one2one-call/node_modules/ws/node_modules/bufferutil
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory `/kurento-tutorial-node/kurento-one2one-call/node_modules/ws/node_modules/bufferutil/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil.node
  COPY Release/bufferutil.node
make: Leaving directory `/kurento-tutorial-node/kurento-one2one-call/node_modules/ws/node_modules/bufferutil/build'

> ws@0.4.32 install /kurento-tutorial-node/kurento-one2one-call/node_modules/kurento-client/node_modules/kurento-jsonrpc/node_modules/ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

make: Entering directory `/kurento-tutorial-node/kurento-one2one-call/node_modules/kurento-client/node_modules/kurento-jsonrpc/node_modules/ws/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil.node
  COPY Release/bufferutil.node
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/validation.node
  COPY Release/validation.node
make: Leaving directory `/kurento-tutorial-node/kurento-one2one-call/node_modules/kurento-client/node_modules/kurento-jsonrpc/node_modules/ws/build'
npm WARN cannot run in wd kurento-one2one-call@6.1.0 cd static && bower install (wd=/kurento-tutorial-node/kurento-one2one-call)
minimist@1.2.0 node_modules/minimist
```

It seems error is with node.js part, Someone help me with fixing the same.

Comment: Don't use sudo in dockerfiles. Hopefully this can help you https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-docker/blob/master/kurento-media-server/Dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

I can go past the error which I have received before.

Need to change the npm install command as follows:

```
npm install --unsafe-perm
```

So I can come past the error.